# Printing MongoDB collection documents using angular js

Tags: mongodb, angularjs

I have a collecton sessions. I would like to print all the docs in it one by one  using angular js.

My code :

```
collection.find().toArray(function(error,data){
        if (error) {
          // Hopefully we pass the error to the error handler
          console.log("Error :" + error);
        } else {
          // If everything goes fine we send the data.
          console.log("Collection Data = " + data);
          //console.log("Collection count =" + self.collection);
        }
      });
```

My output is as below:

```
Collection Data = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
```

Please let me know where I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

mongo returns the cursor to the JSON documents and stores it in `data`. You can either operate individually on each array element with the mongo specific function `printjson`:

```
    printjson(data[i])
```

or use the function `forEach`:

```
    collection.find().forEach(printjson)
```

Comment: Will this printjson work in javascript console also ? or only MongoShell? I want it to work in javascript console. Thanks.